# Issue with creating a gemset via Chef - .ruby-gemset and .ruby-version not getting created

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rvm, chef-recipe, gemset

I have included `rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-2.3.3@storesview` in my recipe to create a gemset. Running the *kitchen converge* does not result in the creation of **.ruby-gemset** and **.ruby-version**. But when I run `rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-2.3.3@storesview` directly on the VM terminal, the files are getting created. What could be the reason? Thanks.
Here's what my bash code looks like :

```
bash "somename" do
  user 'root'
  cwd "/var/www/html/APIStoresView/"
  code <<-EOH
    rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-2.3.3@storesview
  EOH
end
```

Comment: Just because you're running from an environment where ruby and gem path are fixed by chef ruby itself ? When you're in command line your not. Either you'll have to set the proper environment variable in your bash command or have a look at other cookbooks for this (rbenv maybe)

Comment: Sorry for sounding naive, but how do we set env variables? Also what are the values for the env variables?

Comment: For setting the env values, it's in the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html#properties), the values have to be given by `rvm env` after a `rvm use`. but consider following the advice you did get on slack. Mainly moving to poise_ruby or rbenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general use of rvm on servers should be discouraged, and Chef+rvm is dicey at the best of times. More specifically, appbundler (used by Chef to create marginally bullet proof binary stubs) sets a lot of environment variables that can confuse rvm.

If you need a specific version of Ruby for a project, I would highly recommend using `poise-ruby`+`poise-ruby-build` and Bundler rather than rvm and gemsets.

Comment: But what if I need multiple versions of Ruby on the same server and multiple gemset versions?

Comment: It can handle that.